# How to confirm "confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive"?

Tags: lhr, british-airways

[Rules for transit in the UK for Indian citizens](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/yes)

> **You’ll need a visa to pass through the UK in transit**
>
> You should apply for a Visitor in Transit visa if you arrive on a flight and will pass through immigration control before you leave the UK.
>
> **Transiting without a visa**
>
> You might be eligible for ‘transit without visa’ if:
>
> 1. you arrive and depart by air
> 2. have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive
> 3. have the right documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country)

How to confirm the second point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you must hold a ticket out of the UK within the specified time. You can't present yourself to the immigration checkpoint and tell the officer you will buy a ticket before leaving and you can't use this facility to stay 2 or 3 days in the UK.

If you choose widely, you could have more than 24 hours to do some sightseeing but basically, it's a concession to allow you to collect and re-check your bags or switch airports but not a way to circumvent the visitor visa requirements (and fee) if you really intend to stay a few days in the UK.

Note that you must also fulfill one of the conditions listed further down the page.